# Why is there a conversion issue when updating/inserting into a Sql table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Error:

```
Conversion from string "INSERT INTO [myDB].[dbo" to type 'Double' is not valid.
```

I am trying to add the dropdownlist index, the dropdownlist selected item's value, the dropdownlist selected item's text and the text from a textbox.

How can I resolve the issue.

Comment: side note: your code is prone to sql injection.

Comment: I was just testing it out but I will convert it into a prepared statement afterward. Maybe If I convert to prepared statement it shouldn't give the error? :/

Comment: I don't believe this is actually the statement in your program, this error is showing you are not showing us the code for the line that has this error.

Comment: Can you please try after removing single quotes around ddlInsurancePlans.SelectedIndex

Comment: Indeed, we don't know where the error is being reported - a compile-time error? Execution time error? What are you doing with it? Using parameterized SQL definitely reduces error-prone conversions, but it's not at all clear what's going on at the moment.

Comment: @aashish - I don't think this is an SQL error, but you are wrong, that column is of type string (varchar) in the model shown

Comment: Does any of your text have a single quote in it?  That would mess up the SQL command string.

Comment: @PaulWilliams - what makes you think this is an SQL error?  It clearly is a .NET error.

Comment: @Hogan Oops my bad. I thought its the integer column. Apologies.

Comment: lol it was VB, none of us thought of that.

Comment: @Hogan I came here from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 so it was tagged as C#

Comment: @codroipo You are right. It was my mistake. I updated it.

Comment: @Hogan  You are not wrong. I updated it. Sorry about that.

Comment: yes @codroipo this question was tagged as C# and the op changed it to VB.  In VB the problem is clear and easy to fix, you need to use conversion on non string elements.

Comment: Why did you delete the code, now the comments/answers make no sense and there is not enough information to help you??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ddlInsurancePlans.SelectedIndex is a number, you're using the addition operator, therefore you're implicitly trying to convert the left (string) into a format compatible with the right (double).

Use `.ToString` to explicitly cast SelectedIndex as a string.

Comment: There's no need to call `ToString` - string concatenation would work fine, although using a parameterized query would be *much, much* better.

Comment: That addition operator you speak of makes `ToString()` happen automatically.

Comment: @user3111227 Thank you. The `.toString` solved the issue for me. Since it is a VB.NET application the `()` is not needed.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. I will be converting it into a parameterized statement now.

Comment: @SiKni8 To concatenate you can replace `+` with `&` so you don't need `ToString`

Comment: @DonBoitnott You missed this is VB, not C#. The addition operator + is not the same as the Concatenation operator, &, and will not implicitly convert the same way.